# How to reduce the speed of iCarousel View?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, icarousel

I've a icarousel view in my app, how can I reduce the speed this carousel? I mean I want to reduce the speed of the skipping from one element to another element of the carousel view.

Thanks!

Comment: Finally, I found the solution for how to reduce the speed.                  In the spin method's action of our code there is duration factor, if we increase the duration value the speed gets reduced.         [carouselFeatured scrollToItemAtIndex:carouselFeatured.currentItemIndex+1 duration:0.8];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from [here](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel),

Need to set this `@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat scrollSpeed;`

Doc says,

> This is the scroll speed multiplier when the user flicks the carousel with their finger. Defaults to 1.0.

look into document for detailed customisation.

Answer (score 4):

There are constant values available in: iCarousel.m file

```
#define MIN_TOGGLE_DURATION 0.2
#define MAX_TOGGLE_DURATION 0.4
#define SCROLL_DURATION 0.4
#define INSERT_DURATION 0.4
#define DECELERATE_THRESHOLD 0.1f
#define SCROLL_SPEED_THRESHOLD 2.0f
#define SCROLL_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD 0.1f
#define DECELERATION_MULTIPLIER 30.0f
```

Change this as per your requirements.

Comment: Yes I've I changed scroll-speed, deceleration rate. it, but it doesn't reflect. Please could let me know I want to change any other values?

Comment: Try to reducing value of scrollSpeed property of iCarousel instance.

Comment: I've changed all the above mentioned values , but it doesn't reflect on the speed, please advise how can I reduce the speed if possible could you please explain me with an example

Comment: try carousel.decelerationRate = 0.3; and carousel.scrollSpeed = 0.1;

Comment: Yeah a little bit of speed was reduced, still I need to decrease half of the actual speed? could you please advise me?

Comment: Then increase the distance between two. So it will give a feel like speed is reduced.

Comment: just be careful with reducing the SCROLL_SPEED makro manually if you inserted `iCarousel` with `Pods`, if you update your pods the values will be set to default again.